# Separate authentication provider in Spring Boot 2 for Actuator and custom API endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication, spring-boot-actuator

We have a spring boot application (spring boot version 2.1.4) which exposes a Rest API secured with OAuth2.
 
We need to expose also the health-check (Actuator) endpoints provided by Spring Boot to a legacy monitoring tool which supports only basic authentication.
 
However, the Actuator, since Spring Boot 2, shares the security config with the regular App security rules, so the only options I can see so far is to protected it with Oauth2 or to leave it not protected (`.permitAll()`).

I try to use separate WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(s) to setup the httpBasic authentication provider for the actuator endpoints and oauth2 for the API endpoints, playing around with the execution @Order but the two authentication providers seems to be mutually exclusive.

Bellow the two WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementations:

1. For the Actuator :

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class ActuatorConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("password")
                .roles("ADMIN", "USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
//                requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(MetricsEndpoint.class))
        .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER").and().authorizeRequests().and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

2. For the API :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Order(10)
public class SecurityConfiguration2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CorsFilter corsFilter;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors()
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
        .and()
            .headers()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/customer/**").hasAuthority("MARKETING")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .oauth2Login() // generates the /login page
            .successHandler(successHandler())
            ...
    }
```

Any tips how can I make this work much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the same usecase and this works for me:

```
@EnableWebSecurity()
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    securedEnabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig {


   @Configuration
   @Order(3)
   public static class ActuatorSecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private AppProperties prop;

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
        .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("info","env")).authenticated()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health")).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN") // Any other endpoint
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    manager.createUser(User.withUsername(prop.getManagement().getUsername())
     .password(prop.getManagement().getPassword()).roles("ACTUATOR").build());
    return manager;
    }
  }


  [....]

  @Configuration
  @Order(1)
  public class OAuthSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  [...]
}
```

perhaps it helps :)